# PDF Silent print with Apache PDFBox missed margins and orientation

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

My Java application uses PdfBox apache library to print silently PDF to Windows printer.
For some reason, some document are not well printed because the margins or the orientation are missing.

```
PDDocument pdfdoc=null;
try{
    pdfdoc=PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfByteArrayContent));
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintService(printerService);
    printJob.setCopies(nrcopies);
    printJob.setJobName(jobname);
    pdfdoc.silentPrint(printJob);
}finally{
    if(pdfdoc!=null) pdfdoc.close();            
}
```

This is my very simple code, the printService object is getted from `PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();`

Is there any option to fix margins and orientation for PdfBox silent print?

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: version 1.8....

Comment: Please update to 2.0.21, start with the command line tool, this offers option for rotation etc. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html The code is different, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/printing/Printing.java?view=markup